# Validar campo de CPF

Tags: php

Estou com problema para validar campo cpf. No meu codigo ele está inserindo o cpf no banco sempre com valor numero 1 e me retornando falso, mas o cpf é real. Como conserto isso?

codigo:

```
<?php

/*
@autor: Moacir Selínger Fernandes
@email: hassed@hassed.com
Qualquer dúvida é só mandar um email
*/

// Função que valida o CPF
function validaCPF($cpf)
{   // Verifiva se o número digitado contém todos os digitos
$cpf = str_pad(ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpf), 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

// Verifica se nenhuma das sequências abaixo foi digitada, caso seja, retorna falso
if (strlen($cpf) != 11 || $cpf == '00000000000' || $cpf == '11111111111' || $cpf == '22222222222' || $cpf == '33333333333' || $cpf == '44444444444' || $cpf == '55555555555' || $cpf == '66666666666' || $cpf == '77777777777' || $cpf == '88888888888' || $cpf == '99999999999')
{
return false;
}
else
{   // Calcula os números para verificar se o CPF é verdadeiro
    for ($t = 9; $t < 11; $t++) {
        for ($d = 0, $c = 0; $c < $t; $c++) {
            $d += $cpf{$c} * (($t + 1) - $c);
        }

        $d = ((10 * $d) % 11) % 10;

        if ($cpf{$c} != $d) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
}

 // include do arquivo de conexão

// Adiciona o numero enviado na variavel $cpf_enviado, poderia ser outro nome, e executa a função acima
include 'conecta.php';

$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);
// Verifica a resposta da função e exibe na tela
if($cpf == true){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO valida (nome ,cpf)VALUES ('$nome','$cpf')";
}
elseif($cpf == false){
echo "CPF FALSO";}
$qry = mysql_query($sql); // execultando a query

if($qry){
echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>registro inserido com 
sucesso<meta http-equiv=refresh content='1;URL=?tag=enviarcpf.php'>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
<form action="action.php" method="post">

cpf:<input type="" value"" name="cpf">
nome:<input type="" value"" name="nome">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

Comment: Só uma sugestão/dica: Cuidado ao expor dados pessoais junto com os códigos. Nesse exemplo vemos um nome e um e-mail no código. Seria melhor ocultar essas informações, ou trocar para *******

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você faz `$cpf = validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);` o valor da variavel `$cpf` é o retorno da função  `validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);` no caso de cpf válido te devolve o valor 1 na variável `$cpf` e é esse valor que vai ser inserido no banco de dados na coluna cpf .

O correto é

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpfTeste = validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);

// Verifica a resposta da função e exibe na tela
if($cpfTeste == true){

    $cpf=$_POST['cpf'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO valida (nome ,cpf)VALUES ('$nome','$cpf')";
}
```

Comment: Entendi amigo , funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 4):

A variável `$cpf` é igual a true. Com isso ele está salvando 1 no banco de dados.

Procure separar as coisas para fazer com calma. Primeiro receba os dados via Post

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
```

Depois envie os dados para validação:

```
function validarCpf($cpfParaValidar){
  $resultado = str_pad(ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpfParaValidar), 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

  return $resultado;
}

$resultado2 = validarCpf($cpf);


if($resultado2){
  //inserir no banco os dados de $cpf
} else {
  //enviar mensagem de erro para tela.
}
```

E então você salva o cpf não o resultado

Comment: boa noite  estou fazendo assim :

Comment: include 'conecta.php';
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = validarCpf($_POST['cpf']);
 
 
function validarCpf($cpfParaValidar){
$resultado = (Aqui vc pode usar uma Expression Language);
return $resultado;
}

$resultado2 = validarCpf($cpf);


if($resultado2){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO valida (nome ,cpf)VALUES ('$nome','$cpf')";
} else {
 echo "CPF FALSO";
}
 
$qry = mysql_query($sql); // execultando a query

if($qry){
 echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>registro inserido com sucesso";
}
mysql_close();
?>

Comment: mas nao entendi esta parte da expressao language me perdoe a ignorancia .

Comment: str_pad(ereg_replace('[^0-9]', '', $cpf), 11, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);